# C#: How to send Dynamic Razor Components from Server to Client in Blazor Wasm Hosted?

Tags: c#, serialization, signalr, blazor, system.reflection

I want to render dynamic razor components in **Blazor wasm hosted** project. The components are created in Razor Class Library using the `IDynamicComponent` interface. The Blazor server-side loads the dlls and stores them into an `IEnumerable<Type>`. The issue is that I can't send individual components of `System.Type` to the client-side via SignalR and cast to `IDynamicComponent`.

IDynamicComponent.cs

```
public interface IDynamicComponent
{
    IDictionary<Type,Type> InjectableDependencies { get; }
    IDictionary<string,string> Parameters { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    Type Component { get;}
}
```

**Component Example**

MyComponent.cs

```
public class MyComponent : IDynamicComponent
{
    public IDictionary<Type, Type> InjectableDependencies => new Dictionary<Type, Type>();
    public IDictionary<string, string> Parameters => new Dictionary<string, string>();
    public string Name => "Example1";
    public Type Component => typeof(Component1);

}
```

Component1.razor

```
<h1>Counter</h1>
<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;
    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

**Blazor Server-Side**
Loading the components

```
public IEnumerable<Type> Components { get; private set; }

// Loads the dlls and stores the components in the 'IEnumerable<Type>'
public void LoadComponents(string path)
{
    var components = new List<Type>();
    var assemblies = LoadAssemblies(path);

    foreach (var asm in assemblies)
    {
        var types = GetTypesWithInterface(asm);
        foreach (var typ in types) components.Add(typ);
    }
    Components = components;
}

// Gets the component by name
public IDynamicComponent GetComponentByName(string name)
{
     return Components.Select(x => (IDynamicComponent)Activator.CreateInstance(x))
            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

**SignalR Function at the Server**

```
 // Sends a component to client via SignalR when requested.
 public async Task GetPlugin()
 {
    // Converting component of System.Type to object to send to client
    string typeName = Component.FullName;
    Type type = GetTypeFrom(typeName);
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    string component = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
    
    await myHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("Plugin", component);
 }

private Type GetTypeFrom(string valueType)
        {
            var type = Type.GetType(valueType);
            if (type != null)
                return type;

            try
            {
                var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();

                //To speed things up, we check first in the already loaded assemblies.
                foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
                {
                    type = assembly.GetType(valueType);
                    if (type != null)
                        break;
                }
                if (type != null)
                    return type;

                var loadedAssemblies = assemblies.ToList();

                foreach (var loadedAssembly in assemblies)
                {
                    foreach (AssemblyName referencedAssemblyName in loadedAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
                    {
                        var found = loadedAssemblies.All(x => x.GetName() != referencedAssemblyName);

                        if (!found)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                var referencedAssembly = Assembly.Load(referencedAssemblyName);
                                type = referencedAssembly.GetType(valueType);
                                if (type != null)
                                    break;
                                loadedAssemblies.Add(referencedAssembly);
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                //We will ignore this, because the Type might still be in one of the other Assemblies.
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                //throw my custom exception    
            }

            if (type == null)
            {
                //throw my custom exception.
            }

            return type;
        }
```

**SignalR at Client-Side**

The error occurs when trying to cast object to `IDynamicComponent`.

```
public IDynamicComponent Component;
    
hubConnection.On<string>("Plugin", (component) =>
{
    object obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object>(component);
    Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());

    // Casting object to 'IDynamicComponent' to be able to render
    Component = (IDynamicComponent)obj; // Error occurs here

    UpdateBlazorUIEvent?.Invoke();
});
```

**Browser Console Output**

```
{ 
  "InjectableDependencies": {}, 
  "Parameters": {},
  "Name": "Counter",
  "Component": "PluginOne.Component1, PluginOne, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null",
}

Specified cast is not valid.
```

How can I successfully send a component (`System.Type`) to the client-side and cast to `IDynamicComponent` to render the UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass `Types` through Json.  That's exactly what the error says - Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported.

You need to use reflection to get the actual fully qualified class name as a string, pass that via `IDynamicComponent`, say `myassembly.myclass`,  and then get a new instance of the object at the other end.

The code looks something like:

```
// In Code
var myclass = typeof(myComponent).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

```
// Out code
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var mytype = assembly.GetTypes().First(item => item.Name.Equals(className));
var myclass = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

There are similar problems with passing the generic type `object`. It bit me recently!

Comment: Your answer is a bit not clear for me. This is my first time using this concept of loading dynamic components. Perhaps if you can add more info it will clarify what I need to do.

Comment: Hi, yes, please clarify..  Your WASM application and the server API controller communicate via Json.  What I hoped you would understand is that you can't pass an object of type Type with Json, and therefore can't pass any objects of `IDynamicComponent` via Json because the Interface contains objects of type Type.  You need to look at different strategies to achieve your goal.  One such way is to pass the classname in the Json WASM to Controller data exchange.  Without a full view of what your trying to achieve, we can only make suggestions of how you can achieve your goal

Comment: Hi Shaun. I managed to get the new instance of the object and serialize it with newtonsoft and send to client via signalr. However, in client I can't seem to convert the object I received to IDynamicComponent. Do you know how I can do that?

Comment: If it compiles, run and put a stop on where you can see the "object" that newtonsoft serializes/deserializes.  Post what you see.

Comment: Hi Shaun. I posted the output of the object shown in the browser console. However, I can't find a way to cast this object to `IDynamicComponent` to render the UI. I also improved the formatting of the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Will have a look tomorrow for you